# Nagios Schedule a Check on Command Line

Tags: authentication, nagios

I use Nagios Core 3.5.1. In order to skip the HTTP authentication (guest user without password could also be tedious), I turn off the Nagios authentication based on [this article](http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26686). (even though turning off authentication is not recommended in any situation)

The great thing right now is every one could go to my Nagios address to view, but not able to change anything. However, this unfortunately also disable my ability to reschedule a check, etc. Because I can not log out guest and log in my authenticated account.

So I give up [rescheduling a check on the web interface](https://kb.groundworkopensource.com/display/DOC66/How+to+reschedule+a+next+check+for+a+host+or+service), but turning to do so in command line. I am wondering if there is a way to reschedule a check on command line?

Any insight would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheduling a check on the command line is pretty easy.  You need to enable the [external commands](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/extcommands.html) ([command list](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandlist.php)).  Then all you need is the name of the service, the name of the host, and the unix_time for when you want the check to run.

Here are a couple examples

```
NAGIOS_CMD_SOCKET='/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd'
# schedule a service check
/usr/bin/printf "[%lu] SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK;%s;%s;%s\n" \
                  $(date +%s) \
                  "host_name" \
                  "service_name" \
                  $(date +%s) | tee -a $NAGIOS_CMD_SOCKET

# schedule a host check
/usr/bin/printf "[%lu] SCHEDULE_HOST_CHECK;%s;%s\n" \
                 $(date +%s) \
                 "host_name" \
                 $(date +%s) | tee -a $NAGIOS_CMD_SOCKET
```